# I'm am trying to have a responsive navigation bar for small screens, how can I change the left links to a css drop-down menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

This is my HTML (top):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/style.css" media="(min-width: 808px)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/mobile.css" media="(max-width: 807px)" type="text/css" />
    <script src = "script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "nav">
        <div class = "container">
            <ul class="pull-left">
                <li class = "content"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li class = "content"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                <li class = "content"><a href="/projects">Projects</a></li>
                <li class = "content"><a href="/recruit">recruting</a></li>
                <li class = "content"><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="pull-right">
                <li><a href = "index.html">Exatreo</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class = "top_page">
            <h1 class = "mainTitle">title</h1>
            <p class = "slogan">Slogan</p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

And here is my current CSS for the navigation in the `style.css` file:

```
.nav li {
    display: inline;
}
.nav a {
    border-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    border-style: solid;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    color: #e74c3c;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 14px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav a:hover {
    border-color: #e74c3c;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.nav {
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

How can I say, with HTML/jQuery/Javascript/CSS, if the screen is less than 808px wide, then the `.pull-left` becomes a button, and when I click this button, the usual content displays below.
Thanks!

Comment: Added that to a jsfiddle so people can see and try what you`re describing. http://jsfiddle.net/4qpjty88/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @media queries to get device resolution or screen position and apply css updates based on that.

- [Example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Or you can use bootstrap. [Here](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/) is an example. Change the browser width and you'll see.

You can create a mobile menu disabled, and based on the @media display it or not, hiding the default menu.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thx, but I want the whole `.pull-left` content to be visible when clicking a button that would of replaced it

Answer (score 0):

firstly you need to involve javascript. one way is that you detect the navigator on page load:
1: `var isMobile =(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i).test(navigator.userAgent);` (use which ones is suitable for you). you can also use the window width properties if you do not want to design for specific devices, just for specific screens. And necessary functions / bindings etc for that dropdown or any type of menu.
2: you need to have two templates for mobile and others, and according to the navigator, load one of them like:

```
var container = document.getElementbyId("navContainer"); if (isMobile) { container.innerHTML = <'mobile-template'> } else { container.innerHTML = <'default-template'>;
```

Comment: how can I load the mobile template?

Comment: what js framework / library you use I don't know but, one way is that you attach the both templates side by side (I am assuming you are using vanilla js), then according to variable, you can add class (elem.classList.add("your-class"), or by using selector you can remove from the dom (elem.remove()) or style like "display: none;". other option is a xhr request to the template location's url and load it async

Comment: cool. it's very easy for angular: <div ng-if="mobile"> -- mobile html design -- </div> <div ng-if="!mobile"> -- default html design -- </div>